# Scrapy download image as webp with transparency instead of jpg

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Scrapy seems to download images as jpg by default, but I need images with transparency maintained. So how would you download an image as a webp with scrapy while keeping the transparent background?

So far I just used a basic setup from the scrapy download images docs:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html

I did noticed it mentions it converts all images to jpg in the pipeline.

> The Images Pipeline has a few extra functions for processing images:
>
> Convert all downloaded images to a common format (JPG) and mode (RGB)
>
> Thumbnail generation
>
> Check images width/height to make sure they meet a minimum constraint

So I've been trying to figure out exactly where and how to change the image format.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging for info, I turned to asking chatGPT about it. It mentioned overriding a convert_image function, it didn't give any answers that actually downloaded the image in a non-jpg format.

So I searched for the API docs or source code for the scrapy image pipeline and came across this:

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/pipelines/images.html#ImagesPipeline

And saw there was indeed a convert_image function that was turning all scraped images into jpgs. In particular the if block checking for any images not in the "RGB" format and converting it into the jpg format.

```
def convert_image(self, image, size=None, response_body=None):
    if response_body is None:
        warnings.warn(
            f"{self.__class__.__name__}.convert_image() method called in a deprecated way, "
            "method called without response_body argument.",
            category=ScrapyDeprecationWarning,
            stacklevel=2,
        )

    if image.format in ("PNG", "WEBP") and image.mode == "RGBA":
        background = self._Image.new("RGBA", image.size, (255, 255, 255))
        background.paste(image, image)
        image = background.convert("RGB")
    elif image.mode == "P":
        image = image.convert("RGBA")
        background = self._Image.new("RGBA", image.size, (255, 255, 255))
        background.paste(image, image)
        image = background.convert("RGB")
    elif image.mode != "RGB":
        image = image.convert("RGB")

    if size:
        image = image.copy()
        try:
            # Image.Resampling.LANCZOS was added in Pillow 9.1.0
            # remove this try except block,
            # when updating the minimum requirements for Pillow.
            resampling_filter = self._Image.Resampling.LANCZOS
        except AttributeError:
            resampling_filter = self._Image.ANTIALIAS
        image.thumbnail(size, resampling_filter)
    elif response_body is not None and image.format == "JPEG":
        return image, response_body

    buf = BytesIO()
    image.save(buf, "JPEG")
    return image, buf
```

So in the pipelines.py file I made a custom ImagePipeline and just commented out the block that checked for none "RGB" images and made sure it saved the image in its original format at the bottom like so:

```
class DownloadImageAsOriginalFormatPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
def convert_image(self, image, size=None, response_body=None):
    if response_body is None:
        warnings.warn(
            f"{self.__class__.__name__}.convert_image() method called in a deprecated way, "
            "method called without response_body argument.",
            category=ScrapyDeprecationWarning,
            stacklevel=2,
        )

    # if image.format in ("PNG", "WEBP") and image.mode == "RGBA":
        # background = self._Image.new("RGBA", image.size, (255, 255, 255))
        # background.paste(image, image)
        # image = background.convert("RGB")
    # elif image.mode == "P":
        # image = image.convert("RGBA")
        # background = self._Image.new("RGBA", image.size, (255, 255, 255))
        # background.paste(image, image)
        # image = background.convert("RGB")
    # elif image.mode != "RGB":
        # image = image.convert("RGB")

    if size:
        image = image.copy()
        try:
            # Image.Resampling.LANCZOS was added in Pillow 9.1.0
            # remove this try except block,
            # when updating the minimum requirements for Pillow.
            resampling_filter = self._Image.Resampling.LANCZOS
        except AttributeError:
            resampling_filter = self._Image.ANTIALIAS
        image.thumbnail(size, resampling_filter)
    elif response_body is not None: #and image.format == "JPEG":
        return image, response_body

    buf = BytesIO()

    # Get original image format
    image_format = image.format
    print('image format:', image_format)

    # Saving the downloaded image in the same format as the original
    image.save(buf, image_format)
    return image, buf
```

Now the images are downloaded in png format with any transparency left as is. Though I havent figured out how to leave them as webp yet.